# How can I graph the Lines of Code history for git repo?

Tags: git

Basically I want to get the number of lines-of-code in the repository after each commit.

The only (really crappy) ways I have found is to use `git filter-branch` to run `wc -l *`, and a script that runs `git reset --hard` on each commit, then runs `wc -l`

To make it a bit clearer, when the tool is run, it would output the lines of code of the very first commit, then the second and so on. This is what I want the tool to output (as an example):

```
me@something:~/$ gitsloc --branch master
10
48
153
450
1734
1542
```

I've played around with the ruby 'git' library, but the closest I found was using the `.lines()` method on a diff, which seems like it should give the added lines (but does not: it returns 0 when you delete lines for example)

```rb
require 'rubygems'
require 'git'

total = 0
g = Git.open(working_dir = '/Users/dbr/Desktop/code_projects/tvdb_api')    

last = nil
g.log.each do |cur|
  diff = g.diff(last, cur)
  total = total + diff.lines
  puts total
  last = cur
end
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You might also consider [gitstats](http://gitstats.sourceforge.net/), which generates this graph as an html file.

Comment: it does indeed produce a # of lines graph but it's pretty tiny.

Comment: (@omouse - it also emits a # of lines by date data file, which you can graph in an app of your choice)

Answer (score 25):

You may get both added and removed lines with git log, like:

```
git log --shortstat --reverse --pretty=oneline
```

From this, you can write a similar script to the one you did using this info. In python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

"""
Display the per-commit size of the current git branch.
"""

import subprocess
import re
import sys

def main(argv):
  git = subprocess.Popen(["git", "log", "--shortstat", "--reverse",
                        "--pretty=oneline"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  out, err = git.communicate()
  total_files, total_insertions, total_deletions = 0, 0, 0
  for line in out.split('\n'):
    if not line: continue
    if line[0] != ' ': 
      # This is a description line
      hash, desc = line.split(" ", 1)
    else:
      # This is a stat line
      data = re.findall(
        ' (\d+) files changed, (\d+) insertions\(\+\), (\d+) deletions\(-\)', 
        line)
      files, insertions, deletions = ( int(x) for x in data[0] )
      total_files += files
      total_insertions += insertions
      total_deletions += deletions
      print "%s: %d files, %d lines" % (hash, total_files,
                                        total_insertions - total_deletions)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Comment: `if not line.strip(): continue` might be more robust.

Comment: `argv` is not used in `main()`

Comment: (copied from old answer) That's perfect! I was intending to write it in Python, but I happened to have the ruby-git library installed, so attempted to do it using that. Thanks!

With a few small changes to the print statement, I could save the output to a .csv file and shove it into Google Docs/Spreadsheet, to generate a graph!

It's not completely perfect, since it counts comments and docstrings as code, and I've no idea how it'll handle binary files.. but, as a script I can run on any repository, without complicated post-commit hooks and such, it's great!

Comment: The regex in this answer no longer seems to work.  git log messages sometimes don't include the deletions or the insertions.

Comment: Also it fails to match 1 file, 1 deletion, 1 insertion. (s should be optional)

Comment: This scripts may fail to get correct line of code when there are merged commits. Because you get the commits by reverse time order then traverse them one by one. But for the merged commits, you can't guarantee last commit is the parent of current commit.

Comment: @JohnWiseman The following regex works: `' (\d+) files? changed(?:, (\d+) insertions\(\+\))?(?:, (\d+) deletions\(-\))?'`, but then you also need to change the line below to `files, insertions, deletions = ( int(x if x != '' else '0') for x in data[0] )`. On Windows, I also had to add `universal_newlines=True` when starting the git process.

Answer (score 10):

http://github.com/ITikhonov/git-loc worked right out of the box for me.

Comment: Please be aware that currently the given script does not work out of the box. Since this is an old comment and new versions of Python have come up, the code does not work directly with Python 3.

Answer (score 5):

The first thing that jumps to mind is the possibility of your git history having a nonlinear history. You might have difficulty determining a sensible sequence of commits.

Having said that, it seems like you could keep a log of commit ids and the corresponding lines of code in that commit. In a post-commit hook, starting from the HEAD revision, work backwards (branching to multiple parents if necessary) until all paths reach a commit that you've already seen before. That should give you the total lines of code for each commit id.

Does that help any? I have a feeling that I've misunderstood something about your question.