# How to determine the number of lines of code in each file after each commit in a git repo

Tags: git, code-statistics

I need to determine the number of lines in each file after each commit of a git repo.  How do I do this?

I've looked at [gitstats](https://github.com/hoxu/gitstats/blob/master/gitstats) and [git-loc](https://github.com/ITikhonov/git-loc/blob/master/git-loc), but both seem to calculate aggregate statistics, and I'm not sure how to adapt their code to my needs.

Comment: Related, but doesn't ask for stats for individual files:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23907/how-can-i-graph-the-lines-of-code-history-for-git-repo

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a [post-commit hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) that does this?  It could look something like:

```
for f in `git ls-files`; do; wc -l $f; done;
```

where "wc -l" could be replaced with your preferred SLOC counter.